# Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic in Julia

Tags: python, julia, square-root, arbitrary-precision, continued-fractions

This has kinda been asked, but not in this way.  I have a little Python program which finds continued fractions for square roots of n (1 <= n <= 10000).

I have been trying to do this in Julia and I can't see how to.  Mainly because it deals with irrational numbers (sqrt(x) is irrational if x is not a perfect square, e.g. sqrt(2) = 1.414213...).  So I don't think I can use the rational class.

It says here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic-1 that Julia can do arbitrary precision arithmetic with BigFloats.  But they don't seem to be accurate enough.

I have also tried to use PyCall and the Decimals package in Python (from Julia), but get weird errors (I can post them if they would be helpful).

Here is my Python program which works.  And my question is how to do this in Julia please?

```
def continuedFractionSquareRoots():
''' 
  For each number up to 100, get the length of the continued fraction 
  of the square root for it.
'''

decimal.getcontext().prec = 210 # Need lots of precision for this problem.

continuedFractionLengths = []
for i in range(1, 101):

    # For perfect squares, the period is 0
    irrationalNumber = decimal.Decimal(i).sqrt()
    if irrationalNumber == int(irrationalNumber):
        continue        

    continuedFractionLength = 0
    while True:

        intPart = irrationalNumber.to_integral_exact(rounding=decimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
        if continuedFractionLength == 0:
            firstContinuedFractionTimes2 = int(intPart*2)

        continuedFractionLength += 1
        if intPart == firstContinuedFractionTimes2:
            # Have reached the 'period' end for this fraction
            break

        fractionalPart = irrationalNumber - intPart
        irrationalNumber = 1 / fractionalPart

continuedFractionLengths.append(continuedFractionLength)
return continuedFractionLengths
```

So as you can see, I need a way of computing an exact square root and also a way to get the integer part of the number.  And that's all really, apart from lots and lots of precision!

Guys, I didn't post my Julia code because I didn't want to have a small manuscript for an answer!  But here it is, it works.  As I said in the comments below, I used the setprecision function to set the precision to a high value and it works.  I got the value 711 empirically.

```
setprecision(711)

function continuedFractionSquareRoots()
#=
  For each number up to 100, get the length of the continued fraction 
  of the square root for it.
=#

continuedFractionLengths = Int[]
for i=1:100

    # For perfect squares, the period is 0
    irrationalNumber = BigFloat(sqrt(BigFloat(i)))
    if irrationalNumber == floor(irrationalNumber)
        continue
    end

    continuedFractionLength = 0
    while true

        intPart = floor(irrationalNumber)
        if continuedFractionLength == 0
            firstContinuedFractionTimes2 = intPart*2
        end

        continuedFractionLength += 1
        if intPart == firstContinuedFractionTimes2
            # Have reached the 'period' end for this fraction
            break
        end

        fractionalPart = irrationalNumber - intPart
        irrationalNumber = BigFloat(1) / fractionalPart

    end

    push!(continuedFractionLengths, continuedFractionLength)

end


return continuedFractionLengths
end
```

So anyway, user2357112 solved it, thanks very much.

Comment: Did you remember to configure the precision for BigFloats?

Comment: @user2357112 No I didn't, how do I do that please?

Comment: Oh I see, with set_bigfloat_precision.

Comment: Actually, it's with setprecision.  Change in Julia functions...

Comment: @user2357112 Man, I just the precision to 1000 and that fixed it! Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2357112 I think this is a useful question, likely to be googled in the future, and one deserving of a proper answer, despite its simplicity. Please consider converting your comment to a nice answer :)

Comment: @davo36 (and obviously, please consider accepting it once posted, since it has actually addressed and solved your actual problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with Python's decimal.Decimal, you can configure the precision of Julia's BigFloat:

```
setprecision(however_many_bits)
```

Note that this is in bits, unlike decimal.Decimal, because BigFloat doesn't use decimal.

Answer (score 1):

user2357112's answer is at the heart of the problem and the correct answer to this question.

However, for the sake of completion, the 'literal' question of "how would I get this python script to run in julia" is an interesting question in itself, as it is not as straightforward as it might first seem due to [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#troubleshooting), so I'll show how to do this as well.

Assuming you have your python script called "testo.py" in your current directory (and with the correct `import decimal` statements etc), then here's how to import it as a python module and run the relevant function:

```julia
using PyCall
unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), ""); # as per https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#troubleshooting
testo = pyimport("testo");
testo[:oddPeriodSquareRoots]()  # will output '1322'
```

Comment: Thanks mate.  I actually wrote this code in a different way before this current way.  By using SymPy.

And it kinda worked but I got a recursion error.  I'll post about this in a new question.  Thanks for your help.